# StackInbox v2.2 - Inbox client for Mac (Now with notifications)

Tags: app, inbox, open-source

### Screenshot

[image]
[image]

### Changelog

- 2.2 Notifications, now you can switch between Inbox items and notifications, unread number will show in the scope bar. More of the preview text is shown. Fixed bug where menu item wouldn't show on first run.
- 2.1 Menu bar: have the StackInbox icon in the top menu bar, and it will change blue when you get a new inbox item. This can be disabled in the app's preferences. You can change the icon by replacing the StackInboxNew and StackInboxRead pngs in Package Contents->Resources.
- 2.0 update is close to a rewrite, the app is now more informative in login and updating, but mostly more stable. This update allows for easier future updates (eg Menu bar icon), and open source. Also the deployment target has been set to 10.6 (still only tested on 10.7)

### About

- Checks your inbox, every 2 minutes, for new items, and when it does sets the dock badge icon to a Star ★.
- Supports Growl, get an on screen message when new items are found. You don't actually need Growl for this to work, and you can disable this in StackInbox preferences if you don't have Growl.
- You can choose to have the number of unread items in the dock badge in Preferences.
- Auto-refresh happens every 2 minutes.
- Clicking on an item opens it your web browser (this isn't a client which you can view the site in, on a desktop the website is the best for that :))
- Keeps track of unread items itself, so you don't miss a new item.

#### Future

- Option to hide dock icon.
- Filter by site.
- Reputation updates.

### License

Free to use, if you want to put it somewhere else, please include a link to here.

### Download

Direct Download: http://db.tt/ekLESdj1 
(from my DropBox)

### Platform

This app has only been tested on Mac OSX Lion (10.7.2, though it should work on all 10.7.x versions). So should any explosions occur on your < 10.7 Mac, you've been warned ;)

It has now be known to run on 10.6, and can the code can be compiled on 10.6 as well.

### Contact

You can contact me here in the comments and answers.

### Code

Written in Objective-c, the code (2.2 is coming soon) is available on github: http://github.com/Jon889/StackInbox
It uses some open source frameworks/code, MGScopeBar, PXListView and INAppStoreWindow, ASIHTTPRequest, IGIsolatedCookieWebView and EGOImageLoading. Some of these have been modified, so the code included in the github repo must be used.

Comment: Thought about submitting to the AppStore or open sourcing it? :)

Comment: I will Open Source it at some point, I can't really spend any more time on it, for the next 2 weeks, as it is I should't have spent any time on it at all. I would like to submit it to the AppStore but I haven't got the money (hence it being on dropbox) :)

Comment: Please compile it with target platform lower then 10.7. Can't even launch it on Mac OS X 10.6

Comment: I am stuck in a state where it says "you are being returned to stack inbox" in one window, have spinning cogs in the main window, cannot "clear cache", and my life sucks.  any advice?

Comment: @alexgray, thanks for letting me know, I've just replicated it, I guess some change was made to the API and I haven't realised. I will get on a fix straight away.

Comment: @Jonathan It seems to have "remedied" itself.  I don't know if you had a hand in that...  but, _cheers_! Suggestion...Would love if the window was collapsible, instead of just getting lost in the mix...  like a dock "Popover", or a menu bar item or something??

Comment: @alexgray I didnt have a hand in it, I had to hold on working on it, but I'm glad to hear its resolved. I'm not sure what you mean about the window, do you mean the login window or the inbox list?

Comment: @KamilKlimek I have reduced the deployment target to 10.6

Comment: @jrg the code is now on github :)

Comment: crashes if you click on help in the menu bar, and doesn't show a menu bar icon for me??

Comment: @AlexCoplan. that was the case in a previous version, are you sure you have downloaded the latest version?

Comment: @Jonathan. oh.. I just clicked the DL link from your dropbox.. should I get it from GitHub instead?

Comment: @Jonathan. just checked the app version and it is latest :/

Comment: @Alex, sorry it is a bug, you'll have to go into the app preferences and untick then retick the menu bar option. You'll only have to do this once. But I will fix it (and the help menu crash) as soon as I can, which will be in 3 weeks as I have exams currently.

Comment: @Jonathan. thanks - dw about getting a fix, I've got exams at the moment as well, good luck with yours.

Comment: Does it show the notifications on the sidebar on OS X Sierra?