# Bartlett—new questions, inbox items, and reputation in OS X

Tags: app, api-v2, mac-os-x

Bartlett is a Mac application that lets you keep track of the most recent questions, inbox items, and reputation items on your favorite Stack Exchange sites.

You can be notified of new items by [Growl](http://growl.info/) notifications, dock icon highlighting, and the status bar icon.

[image]

#### New in version 0.8:

- Since the API tends to be several minutes behind the website, I'm now scraping the website to get the latest questions.
- Several notification types, along with granular preferences so you can control which notifications you want for each type of item (questions/inbox items/reputation items).

  - Growl notifications
  - Status bar item highlighting
  - Dock badging
- The question view now shows the question's score and answer count
- No worrying about the API quota anymore. Based on the number of sites and tags you watch, Bartlett will automatically adjust the fetch intervals. (But you might still run out if you repeatedly restarted the app or, even worse, repeatedly log in over and over).

#### Planned updates:

Some other features I'd like to add in the long term:

- [Notification Center](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/features.html#notifications) once Mountain Lion comes out
- A view for new activity on favorited questions

I'm also planning on cleaning up the UI to make it look better, and also show some more helpful information (like tags in the question view).

### Download:

Version 0.8.5: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14083292/Bartlett.zip

### Platform:

Mac OS X 10.6 and up.

### License:

Undecided. I will probably open source it eventually, once I pay back all the [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) I incurred trying to finish this in time for the contest.

### Contact

Here or on [Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/yujily) would be great.

### Credits

- [Twitter for Mac](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitter/id409789998?mt=12) and [Sparrow](http://sparrowmailapp.com/) for the main UI paradigm
- [Newt](https://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-mac-os-x), [StackInbox](https://stackapps.com/questions/2872/stackinbox-v2-1-inbox-client-for-mac-now-open-source-menu-bar-icon), and [SENotifier](https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x) for various other
  ideas
- Frameworks: [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/), [gh-kit](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-kit), [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow), [hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple), [Growl](http://growl.info/)
- Icons from [Pictos](http://pictos.cc/)

Comment: Nice work on this app!

Answer (score 4):

Great app so far! Your planned updates sound good as well.

Unfortunately, after I had the app running for a while it crashed with the error:

```
Crashed Thread:  22  Dispatch queue: Background queue for SBStackExchangeFetcher
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 49 beyond bounds [0 .. 48]'
```

When I restart the app, the main window loads and it looks like it is trying to fetch questions, but it crashes again.

Also, I notice that your post says the current version is 0.8.6, but the version I get when I follow your download link is 0.8.5.

Comment: Sorry about the late response here. The 0.8.6 is a typo. I've fixed it in the question.

As for the crash, I'm not sure what is causing it but will look into it. For a temporary fix, if you delete ~/Library/Preferences/Yuji-Kosugi.Bartlett.plist and ~/Library/Caches/Yuji-Kosugi.Bartlett then it should be able to run again.

Comment: Just downloaded. Crashed after 1st launched while I was adding the checkbox. Every subsequent relaunched crashed. Appreciate the effort. Do consider open sourcing so rest of us can pitch in and make this work.

Comment: Same problem as above. Here's the crash report to guide you fix the app: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0f0NZED6 Hope you can do that soon, looks a great toy! :)

Answer (score 4):

OK, a bug report:

[image]

This happens every time a few seconds after I start Bartlett.

Please fix this soon.

Comment: after login, it crashes on loading some data..